# Convert Object arrayList object to Integer

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList of Object and it contains both Integer and String.

```
List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Using the below condition I have checked whether it is integer or not

```
if(arrayList.get(indexValue) instanceof Integer){
 // Here how convert the object into integer
}
```

But the problem is, how can I convert the object into integer ?

Thanks

Comment: Since you are sure the object is of Integer type, you can simply Cast it!

Comment: Use `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(someObject);` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly cast it to Integer but dont need Java does does it for you.

```
if(arrayList.get(indexValue) instanceof Integer){
  Integer i = arrayList.get(indexValue);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to even do that. Java will box and unbox from Integer to int

Comment: If I want to convert array[0} to integer can I convert  `(int)array[0}' like this ???

Comment: yes you can, But as @Tom suggested, it box automatically.